# Organize large number of handlers and canvas instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fabricjs

I am structuring my application which is based on fabricjs and I am preferring react hooks over class based components. This is how I am trying to organize

```
export interface CanvasInstance {
    handler: Handler;
    canvas: FabricCanvas;
    container: HTMLDivElement;
}

export type CanvasProps = HandlerOptions



const Canvas: React.FC<CanvasProps> = React.forwardRef<CanvasInstance, CanvasProps>((props, ref) => {
    const { id, width = 0, height = 0, editable = true, canvasOption = {}, ...rest} = props;
    const mergedCanvasOption = Object.assign({}, defaultsCanvasOption, canvasOption, {
        width,
        height,
        selection: editable,
    });
    useEffect({
        const canvasRef = ref.current;
        canvasRef = new fabric.Canvas(`canvas_${id}`, mergedCanvasOption);
        canvasRef.setBackgroundColor(mergedCanvasOption.backgroundColor, canvasRef.renderAll.bind(canvasRef));
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <div
                ref={ref}
                id={id}
                className="canvas"
                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
            >
                <canvas id={`canvas_${id}`} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
});
```

I have handlers organized in a class

```
import { ZoomHandler } from '.';

export interface HandlerCallback {
    onZoom?: (zoomRatio: number) => void;
}

export interface HandlerOption {
}

export type HandlerOptions = HandlerOption & HandlerCallback;


class Handler implements HandlerOptions {
    public id: string;
    public canvas: FabricCanvas;
    public editable: boolean;
    public minZoom: number;
    public maxZoom: number;
    public canvasOption?: CanvasOption = defaults.canvasOption;
    public keyEvent?: KeyEvent = defaults.keyEvent;
    public zoomEnabled?: boolean;
    public width?: number;
    public height?: number;

    public onZoom?: (zoomRatio: number) => void;

    public zoomHandler: ZoomHandler;

    constructor(options: HandlerOptions) {
        this.initialize(options)
    }

    public initialize(options: HandlerOptions) {
        this.initOption(options);
        this.initCallback(options);
        this.initHandler();
    }

    public initOption = (options: HandlerOptions) => {
        this.id = options.id;
        this.canvas = options.canvas;
        this.editable = options.editable;
        this.minZoom = options.minZoom;
        this.maxZoom = options.maxZoom;
        this.zoomEnabled = options.zoomEnabled;
        this.width = options.width;
        this.height = options.height;
        this.setCanvasOption(options.canvasOption);
        this.setKeyEvent(options.keyEvent);
    };

    public initCallback = (options: HandlerOptions) => {
        this.onZoom = options.onZoom;
    };

    public initHandler = () => {
        this.zoomHandler = new ZoomHandler(this);
    }

    public setCanvasOption = (canvasOption: CanvasOption) => {
        // setcanvasoption
    };

    public setKeyEvent = (keyEvent: KeyEvent) => {
        this.keyEvent = Object.assign({}, this.keyEvent, keyEvent);
    };

}

export default Handler
```

My question is I get typescript issue like `Cannot find name 'canvasRef'.` and `Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance: CanvasInstance | null)` because of which I cannot set canvas. I want to know is this the wrong way to attach canvas and it's handlers?